# Prove or disprove sequence is convergent

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

Let $a_n,b_n$ be two sequences of positive number, suppose that $\lim(a_n/b_n)=L$. Prove or disprove

a) if $a_n$ is convergent, then so is $b_n$

b) if $b_n$ is convergent, then so is $a_n$

I start with taking $ε>0 $. Since $a_n$ is convergent, there exist some $M$ and $N$ such that for all $n>N$, $|a_n-M|<ε$. What do I do next?

Comment: What is your definition of "convergent"? The limit exists *and it is finite*? So you wouldn't accept sequences whose limit is $\,\pm \infty\;$ as "convergent"?

Comment: yes, a convergent sequence only have one limit

Comment: This is true if $L\ne0$ and $L\not\in\{\pm\infty\}$.

Comment: I've posted an answer explaining why the statement in $(a)$ is true if $L\ne 0$.  The statement in $(b)$ is true without such an assumption.  (In both cases, I assume $-\infty\ne L\ne\infty$.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = L \tag{1}
$$
and $L$ is a real number (so $-\infty\ne L\ne\infty$) and $L\ne0$.

Suppose $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$ also exists and is not $\pm\infty$.

Then
$$
b_n = \frac{a_n}{a_n/b_n}
$$
and the expressions in the numerator and denominator both approach finite limits and the limit of the expression in the denominator is not $0$. Therefore $\lim_n b_n$ exists.  This wouldn't work if $L$ as defined in $(1)$ were $0$.

Now suppose $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n$ exists and is not $\pm\infty$.

Then
$$
a_n = b_n\cdot\frac{a_n}{b_n}
$$
and both *factors* approach finite limits.  Therefore $\lim_n a_n$ exists.

Answer (score 2):

Counterexample

$$\{a_n\}=\left\{\frac1n\right\}\;,\;\{b_n\}=\{n\}\implies \frac{a_n}{b_n}=\frac1{n^2}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0=L$$

Comment: But the statement in part (b) is true, and (a) becomes true if you add only the tiny qualification that $L\ne0$.  See my answer below.